# After query perform i want to reload the same page with exact url

Tags: php, html, mysql

Basically, I have a page and performing a query of delete on current page which is like : dir-lawyers.php?page=4

whenever i clicked on specific lawyers to preform query it is working fine but it redirect to dir-lawyers.php not on dir-lawyers.php?page=4

My design view code is given below.

```html
<td align="center"><a href=dir-lawyers.php?mode=del&id=<?php echo $data['id'];?>></a></td>
```

And php code is ..

```
if(isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode']=='del') {
    $del="delete  from users where id='$id'"; 
    $query=mysql_query($del);
      if($query){
          echo "Record Deleted";
           header("Refresh:0");
            }
 }
```

Comment: Please check your HREF set in a tag and are you getting $id? Please add some more code as it is unclear what you are trying..

Answer (score 1):

First The page paremeter is missing so Add Like this

```
<td align="center"><a href=dir-lawyers.php?page=4&mode=del&id=<?php echo $data['id'];?></a></td>
```

And second thing is Before  You are using $id on dir-lawyers.php page 
You have to get $id from $_GET['id']..

```
if(isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode']=='del') {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $del="delete  from users where id='$id'"; 
    $query=mysql_query($del);
      if($query){
          echo "Record Deleted";
           header("Refresh:0");
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> `page=4` parameter is missing

Use it as:

```
<td align="center"><a href=dir-lawyers.php?page=4&mode=del&id=<?php echo $data['id'];?></a></td>


if(isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode']=='del' && $_GET['page']==4) {
    $del="delete  from users where id='$id'"; 
    $query=mysql_query($del);
      if($query){
          echo "Record Deleted";
           header("Refresh:0");
            }
 }
```

Comment: How could i get the page=4 which is declare after <td></td>. Page=4 is pagination.

Comment: You said it is the same page being called, so why you need to declare page